# Logger -f command killed opening /var/log/messages in tail

Tags: syslog, audit, logger

I'm trying to run this command on CentOS.

```
logger -t AUDIT_LOG -f <MY_AUDIT_LOG_FILE> &
```

It works correctly for 10/20 seconds. Opening /var/log/messages in tail I can correctly see messages printed in syslog file for a while

```
tail -50f /var/log/messages
```

After the tail command, checking with:

```
ps -eaf | grep logger
```

My logger process is no more up and running. I don't think that the tail command is the cause of the logger shutdown.
I would like to append lines written in the application audit log in messages syslog file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logger command will merely log the contentsof MY_AUDIT_LOG_FILE at the moment you run the command and exit, so the behavior is normal.

If you expected to continuously log the changes appearing in this file to syslog, what you need is maybe rsyslog text file input module as described here : http://www.rsyslog.com/using-the-text-file-input-module/